# CVAVR bootloader doesn't start

Tags: avr

*Codevision avr v2.60 evaluation*

- Trying to make new project with wizard.
- Set all the `init` values to `0` (not used).
- `BOOTRST` bit is set to `0` (reset from `0x7000` byte address).
- Project option is set to *"bootloader 2048w"* (mega32).
- Programming with *avrisp mk2*
- If I compile this project as a *bootloader* it doesn't work but when 
  as an *application* it works fine
- *Fuses* and `init` stay the same or get changed, not important as such.

I've got this problem trying to make *bootloader* for some of my well-working projects.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to resetting `BOOTRST` you must also change `BOOTSZx` bits accordance to your boot size.